# Footer's website is creating a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, footer

This is the website I'm currently working on:

http://whybaguio.com/php/about/about.php

The footer is creating an extra horizontal scrollbar.. I am not too sure what's wrong but could someone help me out? It's also creating an extra whitespace to the left....

Thanks!

Comment: can u post your  css here.

Comment: THANKS FOR EVERYONE'S ANSWERS :) I fixed it already.

Comment: @ShericaFabienneOcbania I'm glad that you managed to fix it. However for future reference and for others who might end up on this page it would be nice to know what the correct answer is. I'd therefore suggest you to either accept the correct answer below, or if the correct answer is not there add it yourself and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've specified both 100% `width` *and* `padding` on a `block` element. If you're not too bothered about [older IE versions](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing), you can fix this by simply adding:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    padding:30px;
    ...
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Older webkit */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

You may also want to give your page's `body` a `margin` of 0 to let the footer fully reach the left, right and bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace left of the footer is the default margin/padding that is on the body tag. Moreover, your footer has a width of 100% + padding which together means more than 100%. If you remove the 100% statement the browser will make it 100% bij default and compensate for the padding.

Apply the following two changes to your CSS and all will be good:

```
body {
  padding: 0; // add this line
  margin: 0; // add this line
}

#footer {
 width: 100%; // remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your using 100% with on the #footer and also applying 30px padding left and right which is going to add up to more the 100% screen width.

Remove the below CSS from #footer:

```
padding: 30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding-left: 0;` and `padding-right:0;` on your footer `div`. I'm also wondering... Why the ugly custom scrollbars?

Comment: lol yeah,. i always forget to remove the scrollbar HAHAHA

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#footer{

...
padding: 30px 0;
...

}
```